# How to treat a map as a point of boundary?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, maximum-principle, ricci-flow

Picture below is from 160 page of 
*Hamilton, Richard S.*, Four-manifolds with positive curvature operator, J. Differ. Geom. 24, 153-179 (1986). [ZBL0628.53042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0628.53042).

I understand $f$ as a map from $M$ to $R^k$ according to the paper. And $X$ is a closed convex subset of $R^k$. How to understand the $f$ can be saw as a point of $\partial X$  ?

Besides, how a point subset $U\subset R^k$ containing a function $f_0$ ? It means $f_0(M)\subset U$ ?

> [image]

Comment: In the ODE version, $f$ is just a (time-dependent) point in $\mathbb R^k$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  So the support function for $X$ at $f$ is time dependent ?